# Write to CSV that contains comma

Tags: java, csv

What I need to do is write strings to a CSV file, the problem is some string contain a `,` which will separate the string in half. So I'm trying to send the string "fileInfo" below to the CSV but as I said it sometimes contains a `,`. Does any one know how to solve this as I would be most greatful!

```
public class FileOutput {
  public void FileOutputToFile(String hex) throws Exception{
    String fileInfo = hex;
    try {
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.csv", true)));
      out.print(fileInfo);
      out.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can change delimiter or put quotation marks around the values. Although, I recommend using a CSV parser such as [openCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) which will do the job for you.

Comment: If you do put quotation marks around the values, you'll need to also handle values that contain double-quotes themselves(typically by escaping with another double-quote).  Which is another argument for using an open-source package.

Comment: Agreed, why roll your own when OpenCSV will only take 5 min?

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation I was happy with: [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

The [openCSV](https://code.google.com/p/opencsv/) does also a good job.